# New Hadoop Requirement

Tags: hadoop, architecture, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig

I have a typical requirement from one of our client (a beverage company in US).

**Requirement is :**

In website they have option to show different events , organized in US ,to the customer depending upon the region and member interest.

Table Details in OLTP are as follows ....

[ERD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzjzL.jpg)

Now Requirement is...

When member logging into the site , we have to find out event name depending on event date , member Interest and region as preferred event for that member.

In general OLTP it takes huge time due to huge load(registered user around 3000000 and Transaction rate around 700 TPS.

We have some other Hadoop based implementation for this application also (like daily sales report in different band , customer update/login frequency etc.) , so we have a ready setup for hadoop (MR,HIVE,PIG) for this client.

Can any one suggest me , how we can handle this typical requirement using hadoop.

Only steps or process is required. I mean the solution designing part or the process only.

Any helps/suggestions will be appreciated...

Please let me know if any one need to know any thing more on requirement or setup about  the existing process.

Thanks ....

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548357/searching-over-documents-stored-in-hadoop-which-tool-to-use

Comment: I think you should look into SOLR

Comment: @pratiklodha we already consider SOLR. But Our problem is that we can not off OLTP db. In that we should have something to get data from OLTP to SOLR. Any suggestion on this ?

Comment: You can directly connect sold to external database http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Oracle_Example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hive(Bigdata)- difference between bucketing and indexing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818447/hivebigdata-difference-between-bucketing-and-indexing)